# Spring DB2 JPA Entity Manager Problem

Tags: spring, jpa, db2

I'm trying to configure Spring, JPA and DB2 in order to have the entity manager instance to be used in my spring controllers but according how I have configured Spring this not happens.
These are the two attempts of configuration of spring:

```
 <bean id="dataSource"
  class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource" />
 <bean name="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
  <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="em" />
 </bean>
 <bean id="em"
  class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalEntityManagerFactoryBean">
  <property name="persistenceUnitName" value="fileUtility" />
  <property name="jpaVendorAdapter">
   <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.OpenJpaVendorAdapter">
    <property name="database" value="DB2" />
    <property name="showSql" value="true" />
   </bean>
  </property>
 </bean>
```

the second is this:

```
  <!-- Entity manager factory bean. -->
  <bean id="entityManagerFactory"
    class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalEntityManagerFactoryBean">
    <property name="persistenceUnitName" value="Sample" />
  </bean>

  <!-- Entity manager bean. -->
  <bean id="em" factory-bean="entityManagerFactory"
    factory-method="createEntityManager" />
```

and the entity manager is injected in this way:

```
<bean id="messageService" class="utilities.services.impl.MessageServiceImpl">
   <property name="entityManager" ref="em" />
  </bean>
```

but I have always this exception:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: methods with same signature createEntityManager() but incompatible return types: [interface com.ibm.websphere.persistence.WsJpaEntityManager, interface org.apache.openjpa.persistence.OpenJPAEntityManagerSPI]
```

I don't know how can be fixed. Has anyone encountered this problem?

Thanks in advance.

[EDIT]
This is my persistence.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<persistence xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" version="1.0">
    <persistence-unit name="fileUtility"
        transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
        <provider>org.apache.openjpa.persistence.PersistenceProviderImpl</provider>
        <mapping-file>META-INF/mapping.xml</mapping-file>
        <properties>
            <property name="openjpa.ConnectionURL" value="jdbc:db2://localhost:50000/db2admin" />
            <property name="openjpa.ConnectionDriverName" value="COM.ibm.db2.jdbc.app.DB2Driver" />
            <property name="openjpa.ConnectionUserName" value="db2admin" />
            <property name="openjpa.ConnectionPassword" value="XXXX" />
            <property name="openjpa.FlushBeforeQueries" value="true"/>
             <property name="openjpa.RuntimeUnenhancedClasses" value="supported" />
         </properties>

    </persistence-unit>

    <persistence-unit name="fileUtility2" transaction-type="JTA">
        <provider>org.apache.openjpa.persistence.PersistenceProviderImpl</provider>
        <jta-data-source>file_ds</jta-data-source>
        <mapping-file>META-INF/mapping.xml</mapping-file>
        <properties>
            <property name="openjpa.Log" value="SQL=TRACE"/>
            <property name="openjpa.ConnectionFactoryProperties" value="PrettyPrint=true, PrettyPrintLineLength=72"/>
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

Answer (score 1):

WebSphere has a JPA implementation bundled. So no need to add openjpa to your lib. In fact, WebSphere is using OpenJPA, so you are not losing anything. [Look here](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/wasinfo/fep/topic/com.ibm.websphere.jpafep.multiplatform.doc/info/ae/ae/tejb_jpadefaultpp.html) for more details

When using a `jda-data-source`, you need to have `transaction-type="JTA"`. Also, you should not specify connection properties - they are specified in the datasource.

And get rid of the `<provider>` - the document I linked says:

> If no JPA provider is configured in the  element of the persistence.xml file within an EJB module, the default JPA provider that is currently configured for this server is used

Comment: yes, you are right, but you know some tutorial where I can find a procedure in order to have all the information for configure spring db2 and jpa together? I can't find this information in the IBM website.

Comment: But my question is how configure Spring to work with JPA and DB2 ?

Comment: also the exception Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: methods with same signature createEntityManager() but incompatible return types: [interface com.ibm.websphere.persistence.WsJpaEntityManager, interface org.apache.openjpa.persistence.OpenJPAEntityManagerSPI] continue to happens.

Comment: @carlo I still don't see your `persistence.xml`

Comment: Hi Bozho, I have posted my persistence.xml in the original post of this thread with my the two tests of persisistence unit. Hope you can help me. Thank you.

Comment: you can see that in the persistence-unit with name "fileUtility2" I'm using transaction-type="JTA" and I not specify connection properties. And I'm rid of the <provider> like says the document, but the error still occurs

Comment: what's the content of your lib folder?

Comment: This is the content of the lib folder: asm-3.3.jar
cglib-2.2.jar
commons-beanutils.jar
commons-collections-3.2.1.jar
commons-fileupload-1.2.2.jar
commons-io-1.4.jar
commons-lang-2.4.jar
commons-logging-1.1.1.jar
ezmorph-1.0.6.jar
freemarker-2.3.15.jar
json-lib-2.3-jdk15.jar
jstl.jar
log4j-1.2.15.jar
objenesis-1.2.jar
ognl-2.7.3.jar
spring.jar
spring-orm.jar
spring-webmv.jar
spring-web.jar
spring-jpa.jar
db2jcc.jar
db2jcc_license_cu.jar

Comment: @carlo - if you haven't tampered with the lib folders of the application server (try on a fresh installation), then ask the support of WebSphere. Seems like (yet another) ugly bug to me

Comment: I get the same exception like carlo. The problem is Spring trying to create a proxy class for the entity manager factory. If I understood the sources correctly, Spring is able to do so for common JPA implementations, but fails in the case of WebSphere's customized version of OpenJPA

Answer (score 1):

I believe you're doing the wrong configuration, because you're configuring it "à la Tomcat". If you're using a Java EE application server, such as WAS, you should:

1. In Spring application context xml file

   - configure the DAO bean by a `<bean>` definition
   - configure the JNDI definition for the datasource created in the application server via a
     `<jee:jndi-lookup>` 
     definition; the 
     `name` 
     attribute should be 
     `persistence/XXX`, where XXX shall match the 
     `<persistence-unit name="XXX" transaction-type="JTA">` 
     in persistence.xml file
   - The id attribute in the 
     `<jee:jndi-lookup id=YYY>` should point to the 
     `name=YYY` parameter of the Entity Manager definition in the DAO, this is to say,
     `@PersistenceContext(name=YYY) EntityManager em;`
   - Specify 
     `<tx:annotation-driven />` and 
     `<tx:jta-transaction-manager />`
2. In file 
   `web.xml` of your web app you should include a definition using the xml tag
   `<persistence-unit-ref>` whose 
   `<persistence-unit-ref-name>` parameter shall be the 
   `persistence/XXX` JNDI name as specified in persistence.xml (shown above).
3. Finally, you should create a JNDI definition in the application server (AS dependant) that defines the JNDI name for the JDBC connection. This name should match the 
   `<jta-data-source>` xml tag in the persistence.xml file, **and it is the only link between the JPA definition and the JDBC defined in the application server.**
4. To round up:

   - Application Context Spring file
     `<bean class="`*DAO implementation class*`" />

       <jee:jndi-lookup id="YYY" jndi-name="persistence/XXX" />

       <tx:annotation-driven />

       <tx:jta-transaction-manager />`
   - persistence.xml file
     `<persistence-unit name="XXX" transaction-type="JTA">

         <jta-data-source>jdbc/DSN</jta-data-source>

     </persistence-unit>`
   - web.xml file
     `...

     <persistence-unit-ref>

     <persistence-unit-ref-name>persistence/XXX</persistence-unit-ref-name>

     </persistence-unit-ref>

     ...`
   - DAO (only @PersistenceContext shown)
     `...

     @PersistenceContext(name = "YYY")

     EntityManager em;

     ...`
   - Application Server: `jdbc/DSN` links to the connection definition, where the driver for the DBM is. Depends on both the AS and the DBM used.

Thus, you may see the connection between the DAO -> Spring Application Context file -> persistence.xml and web.xml files -> Application Server JNDI names. IF you're using a full Java EE application server (such as WAS, Weblogic or GlassFish) you don't have to use Spring interface modules; only defnitions in the app server (see Spring documentation, section 12.6.3).